# Align right with center of panel using RelativePanel

Tags: xaml, uwp, alignment, relativepanel

I want to align right of control with center of panel, how can I do that?

Using column definitions does not work.

> RelativePanel error: The name 'MiddleSplitter' does not exist in the current context

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MiddleSplitter"/> <!--get middle?-->
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualState>
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <StateTrigger IsActive="True"/> <!--just for test-->
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>

                    <Setter Target="AppListBox.(RelativePanel.AlignRightWith)" Value="MiddleSplitter"/>

                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <RelativePanel Margin="5">

            <ListBox Name="AppListBox" Height="150" Margin="5"/>

        </RelativePanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I **have** to use RelativePanel, this is simplified to only show the control that has this problem (`AppListBox`), I don't want to use other type of panels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple fix is to add a *real* `MiddleSplitter` inside your `RelativePanel`, instead of relying on something outside of it.

You can create a super lightweight `Line` element, disable its hit-test and also make it hidden. You will want it to stay in the middle by setting  `RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel` to `True`. I call it the same name `MiddleSplitter` so don't forget to remove the name from your `ColumnDefinition`.

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <RelativePanel Margin="5">
        <Line x:Name="MiddleSplitter" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" />

        <ListBox Name="AppListBox" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
    </RelativePanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

`AlignRightWith="name"` will only work when `name` control is inside the `RelativePanel`. So in your case, you can't use `AlignRightWith="MiddleSplitter"`

As far as I understand your code, You want to have content in two different column but you want to scroll the both column at once. To do it, You can follow the below code sample

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <RelativePanel Margin="5" Grid.Column="1">
            ....
        </RelativePanel>

        <RelativePanel Margin="5" Grid.Column="2">
            <TextBlock Text="My Text" Name="AppListBox" Height="150" Margin="5"/>
            ....
        </RelativePanel>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```